# NSTextFieldCell rounded corners stroke not rounded

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to have an NSTextField with rounded corners, for that I subclassed my NSTextFieldCell, and used `drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect) inView:(NSView *)`
My code looks like that :

```
-(void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

//Color Declarations
NSColor* fillColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 alpha: 1];
NSColor* strokeColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0.679 green: 0.679 blue: 0.679 alpha: 1];

//Shadow Declarations
NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[shadow setShadowColor: strokeColor];
[shadow setShadowOffset: NSMakeSize(0.1, 0.1)];
[shadow setShadowBlurRadius: 4];

//Rounded Rectangle Drawing
NSBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellFrame xRadius: 10 yRadius: 10];
[fillColor setFill];
[roundedRectanglePath fill];

//Rounded Rectangle Inner Shadow
NSRect roundedRectangleBorderRect = NSInsetRect([roundedRectanglePath bounds], -shadow.shadowBlurRadius, -shadow.shadowBlurRadius);
roundedRectangleBorderRect = NSOffsetRect(roundedRectangleBorderRect, -shadow.shadowOffset.width, -shadow.shadowOffset.height);
roundedRectangleBorderRect = NSInsetRect(NSUnionRect(roundedRectangleBorderRect, [roundedRectanglePath bounds]), -1, -1);

NSBezierPath* roundedRectangleNegativePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: roundedRectangleBorderRect];
[roundedRectangleNegativePath appendBezierPath: roundedRectanglePath];
[roundedRectangleNegativePath setWindingRule: NSEvenOddWindingRule];

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
{
    NSShadow* shadowWithOffset = [shadow copy];
    CGFloat xOffset = shadowWithOffset.shadowOffset.width + round(roundedRectangleBorderRect.size.width);
    CGFloat yOffset = shadowWithOffset.shadowOffset.height;
    shadowWithOffset.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset));
    [shadowWithOffset set];
    [[NSColor grayColor] setFill];
    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];
    NSAffineTransform* transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    [transform translateXBy: -round(roundedRectangleBorderRect.size.width) yBy: 0];
    [[transform transformBezierPath: roundedRectangleNegativePath] fill];
}
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

[strokeColor setStroke];
[roundedRectanglePath setLineWidth: 2];
[roundedRectanglePath stroke];

[super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

The result looks great apart from borders which are not rounded. Images are better than words : [My NSTextField](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/09/1393265119-capture-d-ecran-2014-02-24-a-18-51-47.png)

All help is accepted ! :D Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
I did a copy paste with the code of the site you said, but I'm still having the same trouble...
[NSTextField with on rounded corner](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/09/1393423741-capture-d-ecran-2014-02-26-a-15-07-03.png)

Comment: Duplicate question, answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930329/nstextfield-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 0):

You may simply choose the `Border` of `Text Field` in its `Attributes Inspector` if you want a text field with its all corners rounded. Or to draw a text field with any one round corner, go through [this](http://macdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/round-cornered-views/)

Also if you want draw a custom all round corner text field, just follow the steps in above link, but instead of drawing a bezier path with one round corner, simply draw a bezier path with all corners round using

```
 [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:textfieldrect xRadius:10 yRadius:10]
```

Comment: In fact, I don't want to have corners that rounded, but it was more visual with more rounded corners...